# Replacement of clear_all_cache method - Smarty

Tags: caching, smarty

I use the clear_all_cache() method and I have a warning :

'clear_all_cache' is unknown or deprecated. in smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_wrapper.php,  on line 57

Is this method replaced by another one ? I tried to google this but without success. Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: Are you using smarty 2 or smarty 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using smarty3, you probably have to use clearAllCache() instead